# TYPO3 does not persist consistently

Tags: extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I'm creating Events and want to bundle them into consolidated objects matched by title so I created an EventBundle repository which holds these objects and I register single events against it matching them by title into the Bundles.

Since I have a lot of troubles saving them I already went so far as to cache them locally which does help somewhat but still it's pretty bad.

```
public function registerEvent($event) {
    //We are matching with the title of the event so we get that first
    $title = $event->getEvTitle();

    if(!isset($this->aBundles[$title]))
        //Then we look up the event bundle for this title, if it does not exist this will return null
        $this->aBundles[$title] = $this->findEventBundleByTitle($title);

    if($this->aBundles[$title] != NULL) {
        $this->aBundles[$title]->copyDetails($event);  
        $this->aBundles[$title]->setEvTitle($title);
        $this->update($this->aBundles[$title]);
        print_r("Update: $title\n");
    }
    else {
        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
        $this->aBundles[$title] = $objectManager->get('Ext\MyEvents\Domain\Model\EventBundle');
        $this->aBundles[$title]->copyDetails($event);  
        $this->aBundles[$title]->setEvTitle($title);
        $this->add($this->aBundles[$title]);
        print_r("Add: $title\n");
    }
}

public function findEventBundleByTitle($title){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $query->matching(
        $query->equals('ev_title', $title)
    );
    $res = $query->execute();
    $bundle = ($res->count()==0?NULL:$res->getFirst());
    return $bundle;
}
```

Now running this I would expect to see one add for each title and then updates - which is true for the first run.
But on subsequent runs there are again some adds, it does not match some of the events to the title. With each subsequent run there are less and less adds until there are only updates. But when looking into the Database it shows multiple records with the same title now. A unique index will cause errors on the second run too as the lookup of the Object fails, sometimes without any pattern.

Any idea why this might happen? I can check to see the entries in the database between the runs so it's most likely that the lookup fails for some reason. But I'm totally out of ideas why that might be the case as it does work eventually, but there are a lot more than just 1-2 entries in the database for some of the events then...

Also confusing is the fact that after 5 runs all events do match consistently with some events being in the database 5 times at this point of time. But all matches are to the FIRST of those entries so it's not like it is not matched by the query, it's just being ignored until there are enough of them?!, all entries created due to the database lookup not returning anything are ignored after this point. Deleting them from the database by hand restarts the adding of spurious content again.

Answer (score 0):

To answer it myself... I just found that within the copy function I copied over some properties of the Model that I probably should not copy which confuses TYPO3 and does break the saving to the DB.

So if someone stumbles across this, make sure you only copy valid data and not all properties of the Model as some of the properties might break functionality.